# Is it possible to stay up while riding a bike on a moving sidewalk without actually moving?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, inertial-frames, relative-motion, galilean-relativity

If I ride a bicycle on a moving sidewalk so that I am not in effect moving at all relative to the ground, will I fall over?

Comment: That depends on whether you can ride a bicycle! If you can do it on a normal road, you can do it on a moving sidewalk. See [this video from the Technical University of Delft's bicycle lab](http://bicycle.tudelft.nl/schwab/Bicycle/touwtrekken1.wmv) - they even pulled the string to make the bike wobble - no problem.\

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-jh-5TYAtJI  First 10 seconds of this show a cyclist riding on an inclined treadmill at the University of Bath in the UK.  He's not falling over, so its possible to ride like this.  You still may fall over if you're not able to ride a conventional bike.

Comment: Ask a crew member on a huge tanker;  they've used bikes to move from one end to the other...

Answer (score 27):

What keeps a bicycle up is a variety of things, but it all comes down to the front wheel, which can move left/right. The bike is *always* out of balance, and if it starts to fall to the left you unconsciously turn to the left, which moves the point of support (the wheel on the surface) to the left, which arrests the fall and may start the bike falling to the right. Then the reverse happens.

You can see this when riding a bike or motorcycle. The front wheel makes small steering motions all the time. An easy way to see this is to try to ride along a straight line marked on the pavement. You cannot do it for very far without turning off to the side.

So it does not depend on your relative motion to the ground outside.
It depends on your relative motion to the surface that supports you, so that you can make these small steering changes to move your point of support left/right.
In fact, there are gadgets you can buy that simply put your bike on rollers and you can ride indoors, as in [*this video.*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LuV_vVRqQmM)

Comment: Man, that's a really cool upgrade to regular rollers. Way cheaper than the E-motion rollers they replicate.

Comment: @tpg2114: [*another video*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7NY5agltOUQ)

Comment: Rollers are a lot of fun to ride. Our club used to do the same kind of workouts like that. I use them all the time for high-cadence work and for warmup/cooldown between races on the track. Way better than sitting on a trainer all winter long!

Comment: "You cannot [ride down a marked line on the road] for very far without turning off to the side." Actually, it doesn't require a huge amount of skill to ride down a marked line for as far as you like.

Comment: Yes the turning of the front wheel is crucial, but it's not just about the rider  unconsciously turning it. Many bikes will stay up by themselves if moving at a moderate speed. The movement of the bike automatically turns the handlebars to steer into the direction of lean.

Comment: @bdsl: I agree. Gyroscopic precession is one of my favorite explanations, but there are experiments that show even if you cancel out the gyroscopic effect bikes still balance themselves. So I have to say I don't fully understand what's going on. Regardless, I know one sure way to make a bike fall, and that is to clamp the handlebars :)

Comment: @DavidRicherby: How wide is the line, and how slow are you riding? Do you know anyone with enough skill to ride a bike with 2cm diameter tires along a wooden rail 1cm wide and 100m long, at 10kph, without a balance beam, without falling off? Is there a video of this? I'm impressed.

Comment: Actually, it has been shown that gyroscopic precession is not necessary. The real force in play for a bicycle is due to the angle of the fork; when the bike is at an angle, there is a force on the wheel that will "steer into the turn" and restore stability.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey The line is however wide standard lines on a road are (about 10cm?); I'm riding at 10-15mph. You were talking about lines on a road so I'm not sure what is the relevance of cycling down a 1cm-wide, 100m-long rail. It's as if I've said that walking along a line on the road isn't hard and you suddenly switch to tight-rope walking.

Comment: Interestingly enough the faster you're going the easier it is to stay on the line.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: I assumed Mike meant a sharp line, like you could e.g. draw with a chalk. But yes, I can see how your reading could make sense too.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey yup, there's a video: http://redbullchannels.pmd.redbull.com/hds/1439051358001/201509/3780/1439051358001_4489437827001_4489139090001.mp4?playerId=1684512102001&lineupId=&affiliateId=&pubId=1439051358001&videoId=4489139090001 (skip to 2:40). It's also been (kind of) done by a bear, because Internet: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=owKQL4JY3UU

Comment: @Dave: The bear was not doing it, because 1) the wheels were concave, automatically staying on the wire, and 2) the center of gravity was beneath the wire, so there was no need to balance. The bear could have been cavorting about (if it wasn't scared), and the bike wouldn't fall. On the other hand, the guy on the mountain bike was impressive, but he used his own leg as a balance beam. It would be much harder, if not impossible, if he kept both feet on the pedals.

Answer (score 20):

By the principle of relativity, you will not fall over – assuming that you know how to use the bike and you won't be deliberately "confused".

The principle says that the laws of physics have the same form in all inertial frames that are moving by a constant velocity relatively to each other. The reference frame associated with the moving sidewalk is as good as the reference frame associated with the static sidewalk. In both cases, the bike is moving relatively to it, so if it can stand and move in one situation, it will stand and survive in the other, too.

Comment: The only difference between the two cases is the wind. At bike speeds aerodynamic effects are not that important.

Comment: @AndreaDiBiagio Well, aerodynamic effects are pretty significant to cyclists: for example, drafting behind another cyclist requires about 30% less power than cycling on your own. But I agree that they're not significant to the question of whether or not you'd fall off.

Comment: btw, on Earth neither case is truly inertial frame, because the Earth is spinning. we just got used to it.

Comment: Dear @SergeBorsch, what solves the "problem" of spinning is not our getting used to it but the equivalence principle: the centrifugal force from the spin (non-inertiality) acts as indistinguishable outward gravity whose acceleration is between 0 and 0.03 meters per squared second, depending on the latitude, so it cancels 0-3 percent of the Earth's gravity. We always face gravity on the Earth's surface - what we normally count as gravity is up to 3% different than what is "gravity from Earth's mass", the small fraction is from the non-inertial motion

Comment: The shortest answer to these sorts of questions is: the Earth is moving! Will a treadmill really make much difference to your "absolute velocity" (not that there is such a thing)

Comment: @RobinHartland , I agree it's the pedagogic way to argue that the moving doesn't matter. Still, people may develop all kinds of irrational reasons to think that the moving and spinning Earth doesn't matter while the moving sidewalk would matter, that the motion relatively to the *Earth* is absolute.

Answer (score 4):

Yes: I've done that. I used to have a device for the purpose, commonly called "rollers". It's like a treadmill for bicycles.

Answer (score -1):

I would say it is the tire deformation keeps up the bike rather than unconscious steering tweaking; at high speed, high frequency tweaking is impossible.

Imagine or if you see the cross section of a tire, you can see it is least deformed when the portion is not close to the ground. And it is flattening deformed when it is in contact with ground. The deformation needs force and produce force. There are many factors. But the high the rotating speed, the high the force (due to smaller delta time). The upward force counter-react to any gravity center side shifting and stabilize the bike.

So whether you ride on moving side walk or anywhere, in order to get you stay up, you need let the wheel spin fast on the surface.

Sometimes, I was wondering what if a bike doesn't have a rubber tire.

Comment: Tire deformation isn't critical to the bike staying upright. Test your theory on a BSO with the tires taken off and you'll see you can stay upright just fine. Penny farthings had solid wheels.

Comment: Talking about Penny Farthings, it is true having solid wheels but that is rubber solid wheels. This clears my puzzle that even with wood tire, it is still elastic material and can produce force though more rigid and thus less stable.

Comment: For those who aren't regulars at bicycles.se, @whatsisname was referring to a "bicycle shaped object".  And a completely flat tyre can be ridden on, taking next to no force to deform it (not recommended).

Answer (score -2):

Roughly speaking, a bike doesn't tip over because as soon as you start to tip over, gyroscopic effects (those weird forces you feel when you try to rotate a fast spinning object) together with the structure of the bike cause it steer towards the direction of tipping. Turning in the direction of tipping causes a centrifugal force which will turn the bike upright again (stopping the steering).
A well-built bike will increase the stability as well as a human riding the bike, because it can supply arbitrary forces to balance the bike. (well trained people could balance a bike that isn't moving)

The gyroscopic effects don't require any motion and the centrifugal force only requires that the ground is moving *relative* to the bike. So yes, it is possible provided that the sidewalk is moving with enough speed. Anyone willing to try at the airport?

Comment: Bike stability has little to do with gyroscopic effects. Somebody built a bike with an extra wheel mounted by the road wheels and geared so it spins at the same speed but in the opposite direction, almost entirely cancelling out the gyro forces. ("Almost" because the wheels weren't exactly co-axial.) It was just as easy to ride as any other bike.

Comment: @DavidRicherby interesting!  Do you have a link?

Comment: Gyroscopic effects have been disproven to cause a bike to stay up.   http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2011/12/gyroscopic-effects-have-almost-nothing-to-do-with-your-ability-to-ride-a-bike/     And here's the empirical test http://www2.eng.cam.ac.uk/~hemh/gyrobike.htm where a counter-rotating wheel was rigged.

Comment: To elaborate on this answer, countersteering is what makes a bike stay upright: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/5341/683